# Pandas Dataframe Based on Specific Age Ranges how to Calclulate

Tags: pandas

## This My Pandas Data Frame

```
S_No    G_Id    Contact Name    Phone              Created Time           Modified Time      G_Source
1   5636657 NIRMALKUMAR 9887515305  2023-06-08 12:28:52 2023-10-30 09:38:19 JMB
2   5748102 Prathapraj  8638333479  2023-07-03 11:41:30 2023-09-12 18:06:32 GDP
3   6123335 Anitha          9840561308  2023-09-11 10:41:51 2023-10-31 22:00:17 CM
4   6132827 Krishnan D  91-9841384408   2023-09-11 14:19:05 2023-10-31 13:34:58 WEB
5   6224152 Kalpana V   91-6399411710   2023-09-30 12:50:11 2023-10-30 15:31:30 WEB
6   6219615 ADIDRAVIDARS    9361071388  2023-10-06 12:49:57 2023-10-28 13:32:41 EMAIL
7   6291239 Samson          9841333789  2023-10-09 11:10:05 2023-10-27 19:14:05 GDP
8   6263310 Kumar           9176573262  2023-10-09 13:44:37 2023-10-09 13:44:38 GDP
9   6347692 Madhumitha  9789403376  2023-10-16 12:46:36 2023-10-16 12:46:38 GDP
10  6346755 Niranjan R  91-9960213231   2023-10-28 23:28:20 2023-10-29 20:10:45 WEB
11  6357752 K.N. Saravanan  9841920213  2023-10-30 10:24:31 2023-10-30 10:24:32 GDP
12  6351222 SusilaDevi  9941813960  2023-10-30 12:16:11 2023-10-30 12:25:01 GDP
13  6366717 Pon Mudhrai Muthu 9956954152    2023-10-30 12:24:55 2023-10-30 12:24:57 GDP
14  6399804 A.Suresh    9677003529  2023-10-30 13:47:22 2023-10-31 18:13:29 GDP
15  6363839 M. Ganesan  9176146184  2023-10-30 17:14:05 2023-10-30 17:14:08 COLLOTH
16  6365628 Niranjan R  91-9943213231   2023-10-31 09:02:30 2023-10-31 14:27:23 WEB
17  6369042 Bhuneshwari 9176375400  2023-10-31 12:13:41 2023-10-31 12:13:43 COLLOTH
18  6369042 Balaji          9177395400  2023-10-31 12:13:41 2023-10-31 12:13:43 COLLOTH
```

[image]

I want this below format My Dataframe Create Time Coulmn

[image]

any one Help you

thanks.........

Comment: Please, be more specific in your question. Share a piece of code showing that you tried already something. IMO, the community is not supposed to write complex code for you.

Comment: How to write Complex code help you ?

Comment: My Data Frame - Created Time -Column   Calculate Age Range (1 - 3 Months),(1-15 Days),(16-30 Days),(3 - 6 Months),(6 Months - 1Yr) and Grand Total  ...? sample image file upload my dataframe see image above... thank you

Comment: Try to write a function that classify each created time in the appropriated time range.  Below proposal is just an draft, not tested.

Comment: Example - Created Time Colums   ---Age  and Range wise  Cut Function show i needed ...

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to pivot your dataframe?

```
df['Created Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created Time'])
df['Modified Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Modified Time'])

bins = [0, 15, 30, 90, 180, 360, np.inf]
labels = ['1-15 days', '16-30 days', '1-3 months', '3-6 months', '6 months - 1 year', '> 1 year']
diff = (pd.Timestamp.today() - df['Created Time']).dt.days
age = pd.cut(diff, bins=bins, labels=labels)
out = pd.crosstab(df['G_Source'], age, margins=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
Created Time  1-15 days  16-30 days  1-3 months  3-6 months  All
G_Source                                                        
CM                    0           0           1           0    1
COLLOTH               3           0           0           0    3
EMAIL                 0           0           1           0    1
GDP                   4           3           0           1    8
JMB                   0           0           0           1    1
WEB                   2           0           2           0    4
All                   9           3           4           2   18
```

**Update**

A more accuracy version with `pd.DateOffset`:

```
today = pd.Timestamp.today()
offsets = [pd.DateOffset(years=1), pd.DateOffset(months=6), pd.DateOffset(months=3),
           pd.DateOffset(months=1), pd.DateOffset(days=15), pd.DateOffset(days=1)]
bins = today - pd.Series(offsets)
labels = ['6 months - 1 year', '3-6 months', '1-3 months', '16-30 days', '1-15 days']
age = pd.cut(df['Created Time'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
out = (pd.crosstab(df['G_Source'], age, margins=True)
         .reindex(columns=labels[::-1] + ['All'], fill_value=0))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
Created Time  1-15 days  16-30 days  1-3 months  3-6 months  6 months - 1 year  All
G_Source                                                                           
CM                    0           0           1           0                  0    1
COLLOTH               3           0           0           0                  0    3
EMAIL                 0           0           1           0                  0    1
GDP                   4           3           0           1                  0    8
JMB                   0           0           0           1                  0    1
WEB                   2           0           2           0                  0    4
All                   9           3           4           2                  0   18
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it reply

Comment: special thanks Corralien.........................

Comment: working very well this command

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help :-). If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it to show there is a solution to your question.

Comment: Small Question  ?   Above Answer ok but click All Total 9,3,2,4,2,18 view Records

Comment: @balaji. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the date  when reading CSV

```py
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv("table.csv", parse_dates=[4,5])
```

Then, I would recommand to add a column which will classify each record in the appropriated range category :

```py
def get_range_interval(creation_date):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    if current_date - creation_date < pd.Timedelta(30, "D"):
        range = 0
    elif current_date - creation_date < pd.Timedelta(90, "D"):
        range = 1
   ...
   return range
    

df["range_interval"] = df["Created Time"].map(get_range_interval)
```

Then aggregate according each range group. Something like :

```py
df_result = df.groupby(["G_Source", "range_interval"]).count()
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'range' where it is not associated with a value  -this Error show Result my Data frame..............

Comment: Of course. The `get_range_interval()` is just a sample to be completed. It doesn't cover all interval ranges. Please add the `elif` statements that are  needed to cover all ranges